# Pink and green video after switching inputs/sources on an HP 2210m monitor

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

I have an HP 2210m flat-panel monitor which I'm used to using the source select on as an ad-hoc KVM when I don't have one handy but, when I hooked up the following configuration...

- DVI connected to the DVI output on an nVidia GeForce GTX750 on Kubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS
- HDMI connected to the HDMI output on an AMD Radeon HD 5870 on Windows 7

...I ran into an odd bug where switching back from the Radeon to the GeForce would cause the GeForce's output to be tinted pink and green.

To clarify, here's a photo (ignore the patterning. It's a camera artifact.):

[image: photo]

The only thing that resets the monitor is temporarily disconnecting power from the monitor.

Why does this happen and what's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in the HP 2210m's firmware.

The nVidia GeForce is outputting video in the RGB color space, the Radeon defaults to outputting video with a YCbCr 4:4:4 pixel format, and switching to the Radeon and back apparently causes the monitor to start interpreting the RGB from the GeForce as YCbCr, despite them being on separate ports and the switching being done using the monitor's internal switcher.

Since `nvidia-settings` on Linux seems to not have an option to set the pixel format (and the Linux box is my daily driver and has seniority and tenure while the Windows 7 box is a hand-me-down repurposed as a gaming machine), the simplest solution is:

1. Go into the AMD Catalyst Control Center
2. Navigate to `My Digital Flat-Panels > Pixel Format`
3. Set `Color Pixel Format` to `RGB 4:4:4 Pixel Format PC Standard (Full RGB)`.

Now, both machines will be outputting the same pixel format and it won't matter whether the monitor's firmware gets them mixed up.